# Magento 2 - Get orders that were completed x days ago

Tags: magento2, order-collection

I'm trying to get all orders that were completed a certain number of days ago using the below code:

```
protected $searchCriteria;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteria,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrderBuilder $sortBuilder
)
{
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteria;
    $this->sortBuilder = $sortBuilder;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{   
    $today = date("Y-m-d 0:0:0");
    $from = strtotime('-3 day', strtotime($today));
    $to = strtotime('-2 day', strtotime($today));
    $from = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $from);
    $to = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $to);

    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
      ->addFilter('status','complete','eq')
      ->addSortOrder($this->sortBuilder->setField('entity_id')
      ->setDescendingDirection()->create())
      ->setPageSize(500)->setCurrentPage(1)->create();

    $ordersList = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
    $ordersList->addFieldToFilter('updated_at', array('from'=>$from, 'to'=>$to));

    foreach ($ordersList as $order) {
        echo $order->getCustomerEmail();
        exit;
    }

}
```

This returns a collection of orders however restricting the date just does not seem to be working at all. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
      ->addFilter('status','complete','eq')
      ->addFilter('updated_at',$from,'gteq')
      ->addFilter('updated_at',$to,'lteq')
      ->addSortOrder($this->sortBuilder->setField('entity_id')
      ->setDescendingDirection()->create())
      ->setPageSize(500)->setCurrentPage(1)->create();
```

So I just updated the initial serach criteria adding the conditions within there. Also then removed the filter on the order repository as was not working that way for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can get extract time to changes to **Complete**  status,you should check  `sales_order_status_history`.

At the table, `sales_order_status_history` Magento save order status changes over time.

> SELECT * FROM `sales_flat_order_status_history` where 
>   status="complete"  and entity_id=4 order by created_at  asc limit 1;

Comment: Yeah this is the better way that i wanted to do but figured it might be easier to use the updated variable as doubt orders will change after completion. I will look into this and thanks for the tip.

Comment: An order may have multiple records  complete order status.you  should select first one

Comment: Ok, when would this occur? I am trying to use the status history now but not a single row has complete in it although i have complete orders witihin the admin grid

Comment: Would you be up for checking that table in one of your databases to see if this is normal? Mine  has 419 records complete in admin but none marked within this table so bit worrying

Comment: I think potentially this bug https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9730 is stopping me from what i want to achieve here